# Accessing fields in Unity C# classes (not sure how to do reflection properly)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class `DataHolder` that stores different Lists, and I have a function that updates a dropdown if the `courses` List is initialised. I have different types of Lists (e.g. `course`, `student`) and different functions to check for each type. I would like to create a generic function that works for different types of Lists, and the main hold up is I'm not sure how to dynamically access field names in C# using strings. I was reading up on reflection but can't seem to get it to work.

Basically, I'm looking for a C# equivalent of `dataHolder[dataType] != null && dataHolder[dataType].length`.

[Reflection](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/access-variable-by-string-name.42487/)

```
private DataHolder dataHolder;

void CheckIfCoursesHasBeenPulled (string dataType) {
    //dataHolder has been initialised in Start function
    if (dataHolder.courses != null && dataHolder.courses.Count > 0) {
        UpdateDropdown(dataHolder.courses);
    }

    //code that I hope to do but getting error
    if (dataHolder.GetType().GetField(dataType).GetValue(dataHolder) != null && dataHolder.GetType().GetField(dataType).GetValue(dataHolder).Count > 0) {
        UpdateDropdown(dataHolder.courses);
    }
}
```

Error Message

```
Operator ‘>’ cannot be applied to operands of type ‘method group’ and ‘int’
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetValue` returns an object; you need to cast it to a `List` or something to be able to use Count on it.

eg.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Assets.Foo
{
  public class DataHolder
  {
    public List<object> courses;
  }

  public class Class1
  {
    private DataHolder dataHolder;

    void CheckIfCoursesHasBeenPulled (string dataType) {
      //dataHolder has been initialised in Start function
      if (dataHolder.courses != null && dataHolder.courses.Count > 0) {
        UpdateDropdown(dataHolder.courses);
      }

      // Convert object to object[] or List<Foo> or whatever here...
      var objects = dataHolder.GetType().GetField(dataType).GetValue(dataHolder) as List<object>;
      if (objects != null && objects.Count > 0) {
        UpdateDropdown(dataHolder.courses);
      }
    }

    private void UpdateDropdown(List<object> dataHolderCourses)
    {
      throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to run your code, but `objects` seem to be showing up as null while `dataHolder.courses` is valid. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: You're casting to the wrong type. `as Foo` returns null if the object is not an instance of Foo. What type is `courses`? You need to use `GetValue(...) as T` where T is the correct type.